# Check if div is empty

Tags: jquery

this is my jquery which has toggle. When user click on the #title div, #description div is visible if there is some element. But incase when user click on the #title div, and there is no element in #description div. I want to display some message like "No Gadget is added. Add some Gadget.". These is what i have done so far but i cannot get the result. How it can be done.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#title').click(function() {
            $('#description').slideToggle("fast");
            if( $('#description').is(':empty') ) {
                $('#description').html("No Gadget is added. Add some Gadget.");
            }
    });
```

Comment: please provide relevant HTML markup in question and maybe a jsfiddle. BTW, what is your issue? Looks like you should set content of DIV before calling slideToggle(). Maybe that's the issue you are facing

Comment: are you add jquery file in the respective page ?

Comment: yes i had added jquery file in respected page.

Comment: Does `#description` have white space?

Comment: sorry i didnt get the meaning of white space. And it doesnot contain it.

Comment: How do you know it contains no white space if you don't know what it means????  Anyway, are you just looking for elements, or text?

Comment: ya i am jus looking for element or text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `#description` div might have "white space" even if it is empty. This will work if that is the case:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#title').click(function() {
        $('#description').slideToggle("fast");
        if(!$.trim( $('#description').html() ).length) {
            $('#description').text("No Gadget is added. Add some Gadget.");
        }
    });
});
```

Update: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4q6JE/) is a demo with a white space. Notice that the `#description` div has a gap between the open and close tags.

```
<div id="description"> </div>
```

As opposed to

```
<div id="description"></div>
```

In the latter, empty will be true, but in the former it will be false.